# Excalidraw build issues and configuration issues

Tags: node.js, vite, npm-package, yarn-v2

I downloaded the excalidraw code from GitHub master branch. I want to generate standalone js file. I tried installing yarn and by performing yarn commands. It is not building . Can someone provide the steps to generate single pack js file for excalidraw